# Take info from one mysql table and insert it to another

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take data from one mysql table and insert it in to another so i can make some updates without using a live db table.  The problem i am having is it is taking the data out of the first table but not inserting it in the second.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

 $host="";
 $username="";
 $password="";
 $database="";

 mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

 $query = "SELECT * FROM livetrack where member_id ='000826'";   
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $ipa = $row['ip_address'];
 $date = $row['date'];
 $referer = $row['referer'];
 $string = $row['string'];
 $member_id = $row['member_id'];
 echo "Insert Data.....";
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO livetrack11 (ip_address, date, referer, string, member_id)
         VALUES ('$ipa', '$date', '$referer', '$string', '$member_id'");

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: I smell SQL injection in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simgle `insert-select` statement:

```
insert into livetrack11 (ip_address, date, referer, string, member_id)
select ip_address, date, referer, string, member_id
from livetrack
where member_id ='000826';
```

Leave off the `where` to simply copy the whole table.

Even easier to copy the table:

```
create table livetrack11 as select * from livetrack;
```